# alternative to maven scm connector subclipse (not working with subclipse1.8)?

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, subclipse

So for my project I am in need of Subclipse 1.8.x. This has been well and good, but the maven SCM handler for subclipse is only compatible with Subclipse 1.6.x. I like this plugin because it automatically loads modules (and detects them), so you can store your poms in a hierarchical fashion in svn. ( parent / module + module / module) etc. and checking out a multi-module maven project with the handler only requires one check out.

Since I cannot count on that working, how should I store multi-module maven projects in svn? Store them flat-level (Eclipse-style) in svn, check them out one at a time with help of m2e - the parent, and then each module individually? would that play nice with subclipse? I don't want to store auto-generated files, just resources, poms, and source files.

There is also this: https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-subclipse/pull/4
Apparently that is a solution, and that enables the svn protocol for checking out multi-maven projects via scm (even with Subclipse 1.8.x). However, when I put it in my dropins folder in eclipse, I stil don't see the connector?

The dropin structure can be seen below, should work according to what I've read, but I am still unable to find the scm handler even after restarting eclipse. I want to begin development but this is holding us back.

http://i42.tinypic.com/2465aas.jpg

Am using m2e version: 1.1.0.20120130-2016.

Thank you,

Comment: I never use dropins unless an app specifically says to.  What you have looks like a zipped update site. Why not just locate that in some folder and then do the normal Eclipse plugin install and choose to do it from a local folder?

Comment: Personally I do not use the M2E SCM connectors. I first check the entire tree out to a directory outside of my workspace (I don't trust Eclipse workspace). Then I use Import->Maven->"Existing Maven Projects" which is able to find all of the child modules referenced from a parent pom file independent of the SCM. Then after importing them I use Team->Share Project... to link them back into SCM without having to involve M2E. I am not sure how Subclipse works these days, as I stopped using it mid last year in favour of Git and EGit/JGit, but it worked well for that three step workflow back then.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The lack of response on this issue from the m2e people has been disappointing. Thankfully the guys from Subclipse have recently come to our rescue. They have forked the project, applied the patch and created an update site which publishes the new version. In short, Maven SCM Handler for Subclipse is finally compliant with Subclipse 1.8.x

Just make sure you use this update site to install in the future and all is well again in the universe. :o)

http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0

UPDATE 10/03/2014: Similar problem when upgrading to Subclipse 1.10.x, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717398/where-is-m2e-subclipse-connector-for-using-svn-1-8-x-subclise-1-10/)

Comment: Thank you Stijn for the link.  The m2e people have flatly denied to continue supporting Subversion, despite its being one of the most popular SCMs in the world. https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-subclipse/issues/3

Comment: @PeterDavis, I'd love to see what that page you linked says about Subversion/Subclipse support in m2e, but the link is broken.  Do you have any idea what the new link might be?  I've Googled for it, but I didn't find anything appropriate.

Comment: @LS, after quickly searching I wasn't able to find the original issue.  It doesn't really matter anymore; you can get a working Subclipse m2e connector from the update site StijnMaller linked.

Answer (score 2):

See Answer #4 from the link below.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244645/2754985][1]

> Install the latest m2eclipse update via url. since subclipse 1.10.x
>   some updates needed to be made.
>
> ```
> In Eclipse, open Help >> Install New Software...
>
> Click Add...
>
> For Name: enter m2eclipse Subclipse Integration
>
> For Location: enter http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/
>
> Click Ok, then check Maven SCM Integration and complete the installation (ignore the warning about unsigned content)
>
> Restart Eclipse when prompted
> ```