# Where is m2e-subclipse connector for using svn 1.8.x, subclise 1.10?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, subclipse, m2e

I read that the producers of m2e has stopped producing m2e connectors for anything beyond svn 1.7. And Tigris has apparently taken up the slack to maintain the m2e-subclipse connector.

**Q1**.
My question is, where is the eclipse update url for using svn 1.8.x?

As I realise, svn 1.8.x interface is implemented in subclipse 1.10. But where is the update url to update eclipse to use m2e with subclipse 1.10?

**Q2**.
Otherwise, is there an alternative toward having maven access svn 1.8.x in eclipse?

Comment: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x

Comment: +khmar, subclipse 1.10 does not have the connector to connect m2e to subclise 1.10. Read the question. The connector allows you to check your project out as maven project thro a svn 1.8. To avoid confusing people, you should remove you comment. I have already installed subclipse 1.10 thro the link you wrote. Now I need the the update url to m2e-subclipse not subclipse. They are not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure but are you looking for this: https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-subclipse

Comment: See: http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1557

Answer (score 37):

Once upon a time I answered this very question, [but for Subclipse 1.8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294959/769261) You're right, getting m2e integration is still a hastle in 1.10.x, using the following update site will get you what you want:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/

Comment: This update site doesn't work anymore for mars. 

Its: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/

Comment: Thx for the update Dudelilama, I was a bit late in moving to Mars, so I only just discovered the URL change. :-)

Comment: This solution worked beautifully for me.  I got the latest version of subclipse from the eclipse marketplace and went to that link to get the scm connector.  I am using eclipse Mars 64 bit.  I trolled the web for hours and installed a ton of junk plugins on my machine before finally stumbling upon this solution.  I like subclipse way better than subversive so I am happy now.

Comment: @javaMoca That link isn't working for me now. Any idea? I'm on Mars 4.5.2

Answer (score 4):

**A1.** There is no official m2eclipse-subclipse update site for subclipse 1.10. There is an unofficial project here:

https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-subclipse

**However:**

**A2.** It seems the connector is no longer necessary.

I checked out the project using the "checkout" option in the Svn Repository Exploring perspective, and it already had the Maven Nature enabled.

I'm using Eclipse 4.3.1, subclipse 1.10.x and m2e-wtp 1.4.

Comment: Connector had never been necessary when you perform checkout thro repository explorer. However, connector is necessary to allow "import as maven project" from svn repository in the "import" or "new->project" menu actions. I am also using 4.3.1.

Comment: How do use this github project? Do you need to compile and package it yourself as a jar?

Comment: @Philipp it appears so. You can download the zip from the Download ZIP button at the bottom of the right menu. You could also use the egit plugin and make a pull request, although I wouldn't recommend it unless you plan to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do currently (Eclipse 2020-06 but has worked this way for a while).

- Install Subclipse from the Eclipse Marketplace.
- After Subclipse is
  installed, go to Install New Software and select "Work with Subclipse Latest Release"
  [image]
- Select Subclipse Maven Integration
- Press "Next", etc. to complete installation.

Voilá!  You now have the Subclipse M2E plugin installed.

Answer (score 2):

There was an unofficial update of SVN connector. To install it go to http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1557 download attachment org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip and follow the steps:

> - Unzip the file to an empty folder somewhere, remember that folder
>     In Eclipse,
> - go to Help/Install New Software…
> - Click “Add…” to add a new site
> - In the window, click on “Local…” and choose the folder where you unzipped the 
>     site before. The result in the Location field should look like file:/C:/
>     theUnzipFolder/
> - Click OK, choose all available packages to install, and continue the 
>     installation as usual