# m2e Subclipse Connector error - 'bundle org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core [1.6.0,1.9.0)

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I want to checkout projects with Maven.  However I am unable to setup my Maven configuration with Subclipse due to this error:

```
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201303011221)
Missing requirement: Maven SCM Handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221) requires 'bundle org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core [1.6.0,1.9.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201303011221)
To: org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse [0.13.0.201303011221]
```

**Things I have tried**

- Uninstalling Subclipse and re-installing
- Deleting my Eclipse folder all together and re-installing Using a
  different workspace
- Deleting all tigris folders and jar files including updating
  features.xml and re-install subclipse

**More details**

Version Information
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

My current installed plugins are:
Subclipse 1.10.3
SonarQube 3.2.0

My TortoiseSVN is:
TortoiseSVN 1.8.4, Build 24972 - 64 Bit , 2013/11/24 11:15:39
Subversion 1.8.5, -release
apr 1.4.8
apr-util 1.5.2
serf 1.3.2
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
zlib 1.2.8

I am also using CollabNet 1.8.5 and that does not work either.

===

Downgraded my TortoiseSVN to 1.7.12 which was an older version I had used and I am still getting the same error.

I uninstalled CollabNet SVN 1.8.5 in case it was causing a conflict, but that also did not help.

Comment: Could you please add some more information to your question: the eclipse version you are using (4.3, 4.2, ..), the distro you are using (J2EE, Java, Standard, ...). Add then the steps you have done before you got the error: installed eclipse XYZ, started it, installed plugin Subclipse by ... At the moment, there is not enough information to reconstruct the errornous situation.

Comment: This is saying that it wants a version of `org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core` of at least 1.6.0 and **less than** 1.9.0

Comment: I have the same problem.  I think we're both waiting for resolution of subclipe isse #1557.  Consider voting on the issue. http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1557

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Install the latest m2eclipse update via url. since subclipse 1.10.x some updates needed to be made.

1. In Eclipse, open Help >> Install New Software...
2. Click Add...
3. For Name: enter m2eclipse Subclipse Integration
4. For Location: enter http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
5. Click Ok, then check Maven SCM Integration and complete the
   installation (ignore the warning about unsigned content)
6. Restart Eclipse when prompted

Comment: Trying to surf that link, you'll get an "invalid URL" error, but don't be fooled by that. The link will just work fine as an update site.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is sinmple. The m2e connector version 0.13.x is incompatible with the subclipse version 1.10.x

Solution: Install subclipse servion 1.8.x

- Go to: Help -> Install New Software...
- In Work With: enter : http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
- Select all and install

Now the installation of the m2e connector should work.

Comment: wow, that did the trick. all the available update sites did not work for sublipse 1.10 and m2e connectors. downgrading to 1.8 helped. Thanks!

Comment: This won't work if you need 1.10.x -- for example to be compatible with svn 1.9

Comment: Is there a m2e connector that works with subclipse 1.10.x?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
Source:  http://www.buluschek.com/?p=292
How to install the SCM connector:

1. Download zip: http://www.buluschek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip
2. Unzip the file to an empty folder somewhere, remember that folder
3. In Eclipse:

   - Go to Help/Install New Software…
   - Click “Add…” to add a new site
   - In the window, click on “Local…” and choose the folder where you unzipped the site before.
   - The result in the Location field should look like file:/C:/theUnzipFolder/
   - Click OK, choose all available packages to install, and continue the installation as usual

Comment: This is the correct way to do this as it doesn't redirect the entire M2E subsystem to a different install location.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://subclipse.tigris.org/ and use the eclipse drag and drop to install it to eclipse.
That fixed it for me. (eclipse Luna 64 bit)

Comment: This installs subclipse, not the m2e connector for subclipse