# Maven SCM Handler installation in eclipse (Helios)

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, subclipse

I'm having problem installing Maven SCM Handler in eclipse, I am not able to figure out what else "plugins" i need to install.

**OS:** OS X Yosemite ( version : 10:10:4 )

**Eclipse :**  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
               Version: Helios Service Release 2
               Build id: 20110218-0911

**Installed Plugins:**
[image]

**Error:**
[image]

**Error Details:**

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201312191101 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201312191101)
  Missing requirement: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201312191101 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201312191101) requires 'org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

**ERROR 2**
[image]

Tried:
So far i have tried these links to get the plugin installed but no luck :/ 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez7F9.png). [m2e Subclipse Connector error - 'bundle org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core [1.6.0,1.9.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750014/m2e-subclipse-connector-error-bundle-org-tigris-subversion-subclipse-core-1)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCjVS.png). https://github.com/markphip/m2eclipse-subclipse 
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB83S.png). I also tried with Eclipse Kepler

Comment: I'm also having the same issue..have you resolved it?

Comment: @TP_JAVA: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 and added below mentioned plugins

[image]